# Hide grub menu at boot on Fedora 30

Tags: fedora, grub2

I'm on Fedora 30 and some time back un-hide the grub boot menu. Now I've changed my mind and want to hide it again, but without success this far. 
I've checked the [GRUB Hidden Menu FAQ](https://hansdegoede.livejournal.com/19081.html) and followed the steps for a UEFI machine:

```bsh
sudo grub2-editenv - set menu_auto_hide=1
sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /etc/grub2-efi.cfg
```

After this command I confirm the setting `menu_auto_hide=1` with `sudo grub2-editenv list` and the output

```
saved_entry=c70c61f9381d4bf381ccb6bde6d93c19-5.1.19-300.fc30.x86_64
boot_success=1
kernelopts=root=/dev/mapper/fedora_localhost--live-root ro resume=/dev/mapper/fedora_localhost--live-swap rd.lvm.lv=fedora_localhost-live/root rd.lvm.lv=fedora_localhost-live/swap rhgb quiet 
boot_indeterminate=10
menu_auto_hide=1
```

However, the boot menu doesn't go away. I might have changed something in `/etc/default/grub`, I can't recall. I've reset this file with `sudo dnf reinstall /etc/default/grub`, but the generated file was identical to the one from before, so apparently I hadn't changed anything. This is the contents of `/etc/default/grub`:

```bsh
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="$(sed 's, release .*$,,g' /etc/system-release)"
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="resume=/dev/mapper/fedora_localhost--live-swap rd.lvm.lv=fedora_localhost-live/root rd.lvm.lv=fedora_localhost-live/swap rhgb quiet"
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
GRUB_ENABLE_BLSCFG=true
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I set `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0` in `etc/default/grub` and ran

```bsh
sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /etc/grub2-efi.cfg
sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

Solved it, now the system boots without the grub menu. 
Unclear to me why the commands in the official FAQ is not enough to solve the problem, and why the `sudo dnf reinstall /etc/default/grub` didn't reset to defaults, now if the problem were that I changed the TIMEOUT to 10.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just edit the `/etc/default/grub` file and expect the system to pick up the changes. I got this from somewhere on the 'net, a conversion of the Ubuntu **update-grub** script:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
exec grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg "$@"
```

Run this (as root), then reboot.